# Can you permanently miss the dragon buster sword in Demon's Souls?

Tags: demons-souls

Yesterday, I killed the Dragon God in Demon's Souls. Since I died a few times trying, I didn't do it with pure white tendency. Afterwards, I got a glimpse at the Dragon Buster Sword in the rock and realized that I needed to kill the dragon.

If I get the tendency to full white again, and kill him as a phantom helping another guy, will I be able to get the DBS or do I need to do another play through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need another play through. The reason for that is that you are not able to carry over items from a friend's game to your own.

I should point out that Demon's Souls has a New Game+ mode (along with New Game++, New Game+++, et cetera), which increases the difficulty of the game, and carries over your items and levels from your first game. New Game+ unlocks when you beat the game. So you don't need to make a new character to get it.

Comment: Nice, and how do I get access to this mode?

Comment: It unlocks when you beat the game. Beating New Game+ will unlock New Game++, et cetera

Answer (score -2):

you could get pure white world tendency on your world and get it if you havent killed the black phantoms there yet you could do it that way

Comment: -1 This is incorrect.